# How does Status work for Caitiffs?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Caitiffs begin with the Status: Suspect flaw and their bane forbids them to buy Status during character creation, which seems to imply they can buy it later. Two questions:

The Status entry is associated with "a specified local community". So, would the Caitiff Suspect flaw be associated with their beginning sect? E.g., a Cam Caitiff would be Suspect by the Cam, an Anarch one, Suspect by the Anarch.

And how do they buy Status later? Buying off flaws seems to be discouraged. And having the negative version of your Status makes buying the positive version weird.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Bane writeup, "The Storyteller may always impose a one or two dice penalty on Social tests against fellow Kindred who know they are Caitiff, regardless of their eventual Status." This has a few consequent effects:

1. Since the Caitiff cannot start with any positive Status merits at character creation, and the penalty for being Suspect is being down two dice in Social tests, a Caitiff is effectively Suspect in all sects.
2. There's no restriction as to which sect the Suspect flaw is tied to for the Bane — you could be an Anarch that is Suspect among the Camarilla if you choose. But you still can't have any positive Anarch status at that point, because of the Bane.
3. The flaw here is part of the Bane — you cannot dismiss it. But there's nothing out of the ordinary about buying dots of Status after the chronicle begins — you'll just be at a disadvantage when you use them in the sect where you're suspect. There have been Caitiff who have risen to prominence in the lore, and though they were always viewed with some measure of suspicion, they did accrue some measure of acclaim.